# postgres remote connection using another port

Tags: postgresql, port, hosting, remote-access

I am trying to connect to a remote postgres database from a website that I FTP'd to the hosting service I am using. I was told that port 5432 is not open and thats why I can not connect. The hosting service doesnt not support posstgres databases to be hosted with them so I was wondering are there other ports that I can try to connect to? Or if there is a better option to allow me to access my postgres database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can access postgres on local socket or network port, for the second option you have to enable it in `postgresql.conf`, check it with

```
t=# show listen_addresses ;
 listen_addresses
------------------
 *
(1 row)
```

then check port with `show port;` - same you can check it in `postgresql.conf`

Finally if you can't change `postgresql.conf` - you have no control over ports or exposing cluster to `eth`.

So in short - yes postgres can run on any port and no - I don't think you can do anything in your situation...